# Cannot get vector-tiles pbf format on Geoserver 2.22

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, protobuf

I have upgraded from Geoserver 2.11 to 2.22
and I have installed the vector tiles plugin for the new version as described [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/install.html)

But now I don't see the pbf files, trying to get them the same way as I had before, I now get error:

**400: Problem communicating with GeoServer.**

(My Client is leaflet using vectorgrid.protobuf extension and hasn't changed.)

**Any idea why this happen?**
Was there any change in Geoserver support of proto-buf ??
I've searched documentation but couldn't find something regarding this..

Comment: probably CORS or CSRF - you need to  check the network tab of your javascript debugger

Comment: Its not CORS - other maps (raster) are seen correctly, only pbf has issues

Comment: could still be CORS - images are not subject to CORS but most likely is CSRF but unless you check the logs I can't tell

Comment: I know its not CORS because previously I had CORS error, and I added CORS enable in web.xml , and it's gone.

Comment: Did you do CSRF?

Comment: This is not the problem, I can see the error also when i look in the geoServer under tileLayers, if i preview the map as png it is displayed ok, when trying to preview as pbf it doesn't display at all, and i get an error in the log file: "there is no support for creating maps in application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile format" , though I have checked this format in tile-caching tab of this layer ..
Same map & process in older geoServer works fine !

Comment: For the 3rd (and final) time - please add the relevant part of the log file to your question using the [edit] function. You also need to add details of how you added the proto-buf extension including exact versions used